# How to live search/filter parsed JSON data with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, search, filter

I'm trying to create a live search field to filter parsed JSON data with Javascript. The JSON data is rendering exactly how I want it to in HTML & CSS but the live filtering isn't working.

I'm new to this so it's probably something obvious, but I've tried & failed to find the answer online and I'm stuck. I'm having trouble calling the data to filter it - at least I think that's the issue.

The HTML:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Search" id="filter_listings"/>
<section>   
</section>
```

The Javascript:

```
var requestURL = 'atf.json';
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', requestURL);
request.responseType = 'text';
request.send();
request.onload = function() {
    var directoryText = request.response;
    var directory = JSON.parse(directoryText);
    render_listings(directory);

}

var render_listings = function(jsonObj){   


    var listings = jsonObj['eateries']; 
    for(var i = 0; i < listings.length; i++) {

// where the html template is rendered & linked to JSON data  
        var myWrapper = document.createElement('div'); 
        var myHeading = document.createElement('h1');  
        myHeading.textContent = listings[i].name;    
        section.appendChild(myWrapper).className = "wrapper"; 
        myWrapper.appendChild(myHeading).className = "heading";    
//etc       
}
    var filterListings = function(event){
        keyword = input.value.toLowerCase();
        var filtered_listings = listings.filter(function(user){
            user = user.toLowerCase();
            return user.indexOf(keyword) > -1; 
        });

        render_listings(filtered_listings);
    }  

// filtering it
    input = document.getElementById('filter_listings');
    input.addEventListener('keyup', filterListings); 
}
```

This line is where it breaks: `user = user.toLowerCase();` Console says `user.toLowerCase` is a type error and not a function.

I'm just not sure how to link it to the JSON data. I've tried directory, jsonObj, eateries and listings. I've also tried moving the filter code to different spots, below the `listings` for loop, in the `onload` function but I get the same error.

Comment: Consider using proper indentation when writing code - it'll make reading it and identifying bugs much easier (both for you and for others)

Comment: As is, it looks like you're trying to call `listings.filter` before `listings` is ever defined.

Comment: Thanks. I've edited the snippet to have further indentation. I've already tried putting the filter code after calling `listings` (and I just tried again) and it still comes up with the error, so I think there's something else I'm doing wrong. Also I realised that the error is in the next line `user = user.toLowerCase();`, I made a mistake in my question. I've updated the code so that it's after `listings` has been defined.